# vue bestpractice api handling

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Been reading the docs and googling around for best practice to handle api calls in bigger projects without luck (or ateast not what Im searching for).

I want to create a service / facade for the backend that I can load in every component that needs it. For exampel.

I want to fetch historical data for weather in a service so in every component I need this I can just load the weather-serivce and use a getter to fetch the wanted data. I would like to end up with something like below. But I dosent get it to work. So I wonder, what is best practice for this in vue.js?

```
import WeatherFacade from './data/WeatherFacade.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Chart',
  created () {
    console.log(WeatherFacade.getWeather())
  },
  components: {
    WeatherFacade 
  }
}
```

ps. using vue 2.1.10

Comment: This sounds like a great use case for a mixin. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be easily done by creating some external object that will hold those data and module bundling.What I usually do in my projects is that I create `services` directory and group them in order I want.

Let's break it down - `services/WeatherFascade.js` (using VueResource)

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  getWeather() {
    return Vue.http.get('api/weather')
  }
}
```

If you have to pass some dynamic data such as ID, pass it as just parameter

```
import Vue from 'vue'

export default {
  getWeather(id) {
    return Vue.http.get(`api/weather/${id}`)
  }
}
```

Then in your component you can import this service, pass parameters (if you have them) and got data back.

```
import WeatherFascade from '../services/WeatherFascade'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      weatherItems: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getWeatherData()
  },
  methods: {
    getWeatherData() {
      WeatherFascade.getWather(// you can pass params here)
       .then(response => this.weatherItems = response.data)
       .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
  }
}
```

You can use any library for that you like, for instance axios is cool.